# SQL initialize column to autoconvert to date format

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I get regular downloads of csv files in which i want to use BULK INSERT to upload the file into my sql table. I am using python to automate the process. The date attached to each row is in the format 'YYMMDD', so it is a date stored as an int. Is there a way i can initialize my sql table to autoconvert this int into a date.

Something like

```
    create table tbl1(
         other columns.....
         record_date DATE NOT NULL convert(date,[inserted value],'YYMMDD')
    )
```

Or should I just reparse the csv file and convert the int to the proper date format?

If i can't initialize the column in this way is there something I can do within the bulk insert to automate the conversion?

I know I could write a script to edit the csv file and reformat the date, but I like to learn new things.

Comment: For starters are you using mysql or sql server? Regardless who is still using 2 digit years? 1964 called and would like their date format back. I don't know about mysql but in sql server you will have to write a conversion to get this into an actual date.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft sql server. Its all financial trading data and the original format is in un-delimited 1500 byte strings. Who knows when it was originally designed.

Comment: For sql server this is fairly simple. convert(date, YourColumn) It will assume the century of 2000 for years less than 49. If the 2 digit year is 50 it will assume 1900 as the century. This means you could just insert your data into a column with the date datatype and an implicit conversion will happen.

Comment: got it thank you, i need to make sure its a string first though. It doesn't like the int format when I force the implicit conversion.

Comment: Easy enough. Just add a convert to your column. Honestly you should be loading external files to a staging table first where everything is a string. This allows you flexibility to then mold that data how it needs to be and lets you do some error handling so you can manage it.

Comment: I will definitely do that. This is the first production level database I am responsible for planning/creating.

Answer (score 0):

Try add computed column

```
 create table tbl1(
         [inserted value] VARCHAR(6),
         record_date as convert(date,[inserted value])
    ) 

INSERT INTO tbl1([inserted value]) VALUES ('120215')
SELECT * FROM tbl1
```